# How to read image's compress data (pixel data) from container file on Android? Are there tutorials for these?

Tags: android

1. File file = new File(fileName);
2. Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("Reader");
3. ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();
4. ImageReadParam param= reader.getDefaultReadParam();
5. ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(myFile);
6. reader.setInput(iis, false);
7. BufferedImage myJpegImage = reader.read(0, param);

How can i write equivalent codes for above codes on Android? are there any hints how to read pixel data?

Answer (score 2):

There is [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) for that.